# Sharepoint 2013 app development guidelines

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I worked in .net . I start working in sharepoint 2013 today and I'm confused where is .cs file of .aspx file . I need book or any site to learn sharepoint app development . Please don't suggest msdn .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download this book](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CEAQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sharepointschool.com%2FShared%2520Documents%2Fbeginning_sharepoint_2013.pdf&ei=8O6eVeGyM4XJuAToq5uQDA&usg=AFQjCNHGcLhcS1NgUgExlDEYG1DN1SSY1Q&bvm=bv.96952980,d.c2E) .I got this book in google. I think this one will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Wrox Sharepoint 2013 development](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-SharePoint-2013-Development.productCd-1118495829.html).  It is confusing (sharepoint development, at first), and for the most part, you won't be doing .cs code for Sharepoint applications.  You'll want to do everything client side and call web APIs from the application that you eventually deploy into Sharepoint.  Then, your APIs can live wherever and you write .NET code just as you always have.  If you follow that formula, you should set yourself up for easy migration paths once SP gets updated.

Comment: Not that I know of.  But, if you build a basic SP solution and can deploy it (that's the hard part), and you already know how to call web APIs from javascript (angular or jQuery make it simple) you shouldn't need much more than that.  I think it is the deployment that gets people hung up.